# load angular-google-maps longitude/latitude on $resource query response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-google-maps

**I'm trying to load longitude/latitude data through a service response**, but without any success. Google map doesn't appear. If I put vm.map = { center: { latitude: 50 , longitude:  -50 }, zoom: 8 } outside of the EventProfileService.query service response with needed number(50, -50) everything is ok and google map is appeared. How to resolve this case.
Tnx in advance. Here is my code

```
EventProfileService.query({id: 1}).$promise.then(function(data){

  vm.address = data[0];

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({ address: vm.address.address + ',' + vm.address.city + ',' + 'USA'}, function (result, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      vm.latitude  = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
      vm.longitude = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
    }
    vm.map = { center: { latitude: vm.latitude , longitude:  vm.longitude }, zoom: 8 };
  });
});
```

and HTML

```
      <ui-gmap-google-map center='eventprofile.map.center' zoom='eventprofile.map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: Exact what is the issue??.Can u please brief it

Comment: I think in this case you need to also share the EventProfileService and maybe some html too.